# SQL using more two columns with case

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datatable

I can't find a good explanation for my problem.

I have a table:

```
user   | 70Y   | hospital
-------+-------+----------
1      | 18    | 1   
2      | 70    | 1 
3      | 90    | 0
```

I need to find is a how many people have more than 70Y, and if it has how many of those people are in the hospital.

I'm using this to find is his age more than 70:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN 70y > 70 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'old_person'
```

but how do I find is he is in the hospital?

What I'm expecting from a table is:

```
 | old_person | old_person_in_hospital| 
 +------------+-----------------------+
 | 18         |              1        |
```

And if I would want to and more columns let's say check for 40Y old what is the easiest way to do so?

What I expect from table :

```
             | old_person  |  40y_person         | 
             +-------------+---------------------+
             | 18          |            16       | 
in hospital  | 1           |             2       |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a case for each column:

```
select 
  SUM(Case when [70y] > 70 then 1 else 0 end) old_person,
  SUM(Case when [70y] > 70 and hospital = 1 then 1 else 0 end) old_person_in_hospital
from tablename
```

Comment: Probably better to use MAX instead of SUM. Don't want to get old_person_in_hospital with a value of 5

Comment: @SeanLange why? the columns contains the ages of persons and it counts how many are over 70 years old.

Comment: Because it looks like they want this grouped by user. Or maybe not. Hard to tell what the OP really wants.

Comment: @SeanLange The OP wants to count how many users are over 70 and how many of them are in hospital.

Answer (score 0):

use another case for number in hospital count

```
select SUM(Case when 70y > 70 then 1 else 0 end) as old_person,
  sum (Case when 70y > 70 and hospital=1 then 1 else 0 end ) hospital
from tbale
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the condition to the `where` clause?

```
select count(*) as old_person,
       sum(hospital) as old_person_in_hospital
from tablename
where [70y] > 70;
```

If you want to add more age groups, then you *could* use conditional aggregation.  However, I might suggest that you use aggregation instead and put the results in different rows.  For instance:

```
select (age / 10) as decade,
       count(*) as num_people,
       sum(hospital) as num_in_hospital
from tablename
group by (age / 10);
```